# Strange behaviour in all browsers except in opera

Tags: html

These two cases:

```
<div title=" " >Hi</div>
<div title="&nbsp;" >Hi</div>
```

Don't show a blank title in Safari, Firefox and Google Chrome. (It shows in Opera 12 Mac OS X).

http://jsfiddle.net/a3MNx/

How can I make it work in those browsers?

Comment: i get exactly the same result in opera chrome and IE

Comment: my opera doesn't show that `title`, just want to ask why someone will try this when he wants `title` to be blank?

Comment: What's the point of a blank title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a blank title, then you could try with a [Soft Hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen), that has code `&#173;` and whose html entity is `&shy;`

```
<div title="&#173;" >Hi</div>
<div title="&shy;" >Hi</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3MNx/2/

With Firefox (Iceweasel 10.0.5) it works fine. Using `&nbsp;` it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! (BTW, is there a way to show an empty title? without even a space)

Comment: I don't know any way to show an empty title. But you should see that with the soft hyphen, what you get as a title is a really tiny thing. Something smaller than that could be hard to get, I think.

Comment: In fact, your way is the empty title. You can see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3MNx/3/]) (where I was able to put an empty title) that it's the same width. For a title of one space you should do `&shy; `.